# Passing parameters from one class to another in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to pass a String from one class to another class but I am getting an error.

This is the code from the class I want to pass the parameters from:

```
onTap: () {
                                String titleCompanyId =  snapshot.data?.docs[index].id;
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const TitleCompanyScreen(false, snapshot.data?.docs[index].id),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
```

The error is on the second parameter I am passing (snapshot.data?.docs[index].id) and this is the error:

**Invalid constant value.**

The parameter is a document ID from Cloud Firestore.

This is the code I am receiving the parameters in:

```
class TitleCompanyScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {

  const TitleCompanyScreen([
    this.isNewTitleCompany,
    this.titleCompanyId,
    Key? key,
  ]) : super(key: key);

  final bool? isNewTitleCompany;
  final String? titleCompanyId;

  @override
  ConsumerState<TitleCompanyScreen> createState() => _TitleCompanyScreenState();
}
```

How do I pass this parameter?
Thanks

UPDATE:

This what I have now after the first answer.

```
onTap: () {
                                String? titleCompanyId =  snapshot.data?.docs[index].id;
                                
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const TitleCompanyScreen(false, titleCompanyId),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
```

Now, I am getting this error on titleCompanyId parameter:

```
Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the `const` keyword from the `MaterialPageRoute` and pass the parameters directly without wrapping them in a constant constructor.

```
onTap: () {
  String titleCompanyId = snapshot.data?.docs[index].id;
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => TitleCompanyScreen(false, titleCompanyId),
    ),
  );
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I tried that line and I still get an error on the snapshot.data?.docs[index].id line but now I get an error on titleCompanyId parameter. Here is the error:  Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.

Comment: @LostTexan In the updated code, you haven't remove the `const` before `TitleCompanyScreen`